# How much does a 2 1/2 square of graham crackers weigh

Tags: graham-crackers

I have a recipe that calls for 8 dozen 2  1/2 inch squares of graham crackers, since they no longer are 2 1/2 inches I would like to know how much this would weigh.

Oh, BTW they now measure 2 1/4 in squares.

Comment: @mech - doing it 'by arithmetic' you'd also have to know if the thickness has changed too. I don't really know what a graham cracker is [I'm UK, not US] but I'm guessing 'the answer' will come from someone who still has an older pack, or finding a picture of one & seeing if it tells you the weight & count.

Comment: @mech just because one can use arithmetic to solve a cooking problem, it doesn't mean it isn't a cooking problem. Even apart from practical considerations like Tetsujin mentions, some people do need help with this kind of calculation when they are baking, and that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you provide the recipe.  Generally, there are two treatments for graham cracker in baking/cooking: layering or crushing.

If this is a recipe where the crackers are layered, it certainly won't matter, as you can estimate.

If you need to crush them, you might need to be more precise.  I can't provide the weight, but I think I can offer another way to consider the problem.

I am assuming (perhaps erroneously, but it probably wouldn't matter all that much) that the thickness has not changed.

Thanks to @Chris H for correcting my first attempt (is there a way to change this answer to his? I'm happy to hand it off...)

8 dozen 2.5 inch cookies = 600 square inches

8 dozen 2.25 inch cookies = 486 square inches

You will need about 25% more, or another 22 of the smaller cookie.

I think that should get you in the ballpark.

Comment: You need to work in terms of area, not length *8 dozen 2.5 inch cookies = **600 square inches*** and *8 dozen 2.25 inch cookies = **486 square inches***. By count this is about 25% more or another 22 (you can of course work out the *percentage* change based on the per-cracker area)